# Django best practice to edit packages

Tags: django

What is the best way to edit python packages for Django? I am aware it is advisable not to edit the site packages as those changes are overwritten by install from requirements.txt. And also that I use template resolution to make template changes.

Yet what about views? If I need to edit views is there a similar view resolution? Can you call two functions from one URL? Or should I just copy the package into the local project directory instead?

I generally prefer pip installations over cloning as it automatically installs dependencies. 
Hence the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could sublcass those views you want to modify and change the needed parts, or maybe if you need to to extra works you can call the as_view() method of that class from yours, as shown here

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#an-alternative-better-solution

Comment: where would I save these sub class views? create a new app?

Comment: @eol probably yes, keeping focused and small apps is usually a good practice, but your mileage may vary, maybe putting them in your main app models.py should also be fine.